# focus wpf window on short cut key

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts

I have created a WPF application, where if user press ctl + alt + s, my WPF application textbox needs to be focused.

Example: if you press ctl+w, automatically word web will get focused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx), define a [KeyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) and create a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) which does the focusing.

```
  <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding  Command="{Binding MyFocusCommand}" Key="S" Modifiers="Control+Alt"/>
  </Window.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Alt) && 
        e.Key == Key.S)
    { 
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use PreviewKeyDown. Otherwise the Window will be the last control to get the event, and won't even see it if one of the child controls handles the event.

Comment: @Andy - I agree, this is better. Thank you. Updated.

Comment: Congratuations! 10k in 48 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using low level keyboard hook

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: That would work, but sounds like overkill for what the OP wants. Easier to just subscribe to an event.